# PHP file upload name change with preg_replace

Tags: php, file, upload, preg-replace

Im trying to make my file uploades more safe-proof, so that no link will be broken. Ive tried to write a code thats first remove all bad url characters and if the same name exists it should increase a number after the filename.

My code works fine with the increased number on duplicate name, but the string like: hi this is a test - does not change to hithisisatest

The code im trying to run is as followed:

```
if ($myFile["error"] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        CUSTOM HEADER
        exit;
    }

    // ensure a safe filename
    $name = preg_replace("/[^a-z0-9_\.\-[:space:]]/i", "_", $myFile["name"]);

    // don't overwrite an existing file
    $i = 0;
    $parts = pathinfo($name);
    while (file_exists(UPLOAD_DIR . $name)) {
        $i++;
        $name = $parts["filename"] . "-" . $i . "." . $parts["extension"];
    }

    // preserve file from temporary directory
    $success = move_uploaded_file($myFile["tmp_name"],
        UPLOAD_DIR . $name);

    if (!$success) { 
        CUSTOM HEADER
        exit;
    }
```

Comment: it won't answer your question, but what I do with uploads is:
$arr = explode($name, '.');
if (!isset($a[1))exit // die whatver;
$ext = $arr[1];
if ($ext !== 'jpg png and so on){ die;}
$filename = md5(time().microtime().'.'.$ext;
sorry if it is unproperate

Comment: can you define - "does not change" - is the string exactly the same, or does some change such as invalid character removal work ok but the removal of spaces does not?

Comment: look at preg_replace, and change [:space:] to something more like /\s+/

Comment: ohh ya my bad. only spaces wont go away. i will try  /\s+/ asap. brb

Comment: just tried to insert  /\s+/ instead of [:space:], now the uploaded file return "-1.ext" The file name is gone but the increased number still gets send.

Comment: Your script is working for me. Please show me an input filename.

Comment: "analyse of kuppet.docx" could be an input filename

Answer (score 1):

The regular expression you are using in `preg_replace` is designed to keep some selected characters (abc etc.) in `$name` and replace all other ("bad") characters with an underscore:

```
$name = preg_replace("/[^a-z0-9_\.\-[:space:]]/i", "_", $myFile["name"]);
```

As `[:space:]` is listed among those characters, there should be little surprise that spaces are kept intact for names like `hi this is a test`.

Remove the `[:space:]` and you will get `hi_this_is_a_test` for the filename `hi this is a test`.

```
$name = preg_replace("/[^a-z0-9_\.\-]/i", "_", $myFile["name"]);
// hi_this_is_a_test
```

If you really wanted to plainly remove the "bad" chars, as hinted in your question, you should also set the replacement string to `""` instead of `"_"` in the `reg_replace` call.

```
$name = preg_replace("/[^a-z0-9_\.\-]/i", "", $myFile["name"]);
// hithisisatest
```